# How to get formatted date with date-time and timezone with offset in java

Tags: java, date, formatting

I want to get formatted date and time with timezone and offset. recently I used this code for formatting.

```
public static String getFormattedLicenseDate(long date) {
      DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.LONG);
      return dateFormat.format(new Date(date));
}
```

If the input is 1476786856310 the this method returns "10/18/16 4:04:16 PM HST" but I want to modify this method to get "OCT 18, 2016 16:04:04 HST (HST-10:00)"

Is there any pattern to get this output like "OCT 18, 2016 16:04:04 HST (HST-10:00)"

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting. This has been handled many times already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` with format `"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss z (zXXX)"`

```
public static String getFormattedLicenseDate(long date) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss z (zXXX)");
    return format.format(new Date(date));
}
```

Comment: It is ok for my question but if I want to use 'GMT' in braces then what should I use in place of 'z'. eg. "OCT 18, 2016 16:04:04 HST (GMT-10:00)"

Comment: yes, you should try it yourself, you can add any character eliminate SimpleDateFormat letters http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

```
return new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss z (zZ)").format(new Date()));
```

From [SimpleDateFormat JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

- `z`: General Time Zone (Pacific Standard Time; PST)
- `Z`: RFC 822 time zone (-0800)

Comment: Please explain your code, code-only answers are not very useful

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat dateFormat =new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss z (zZ)");
return dateFormat.format(new Date(date));
```

For more information about date formats refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: These troublesome classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. And you ignore the crucial issue of time zone.